# Adding onClick links into a JSON File Without javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I am trying to mimic a data visualization example code from cytoscape library and add links to the nodes of the data.

Here is the example

http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/cose-layout/

Here is the code associated with the example

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/cose-layout

In the code on github there is the data.json file and example of a node looks like this

```
[{
  "data": {
    "id": "605755",
    "idInt": 605755,
    "name": "PCNA",
    "score": 0.006769776522008331,
    "query": true,
    "gene": true
  },
  "position": {
    "x": 481.0169597039117,
    "y": 384.8210888234145
  },
  "group": "nodes",
  "removed": false,
  "selected": false,
  "selectable": true,
  "locked": false,
  "grabbed": false,
  "grabbable": true,
  "classes": "fn10273 fn6944 fn9471 fn10569 fn8023 fn6956 fn6935 fn8147 fn6939 fn6936 fn6629 fn7928 fn6947 fn8612 fn6957 fn8786 fn6246 fn9367 fn6945 fn6946 fn10024 fn10022 fn6811 fn9361 fn6279 fn6278 fn8569 fn7641 fn8568 fn6943"
},
```

I tried adding

```
"links": {
    "self": { "href": "https://www.google.com" }
 },
```

and variations of "links": something but no dice.

I was like okay maybe I can take the ID and add a link via javascript but I haven't been successful.

```
$('#605755').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "data": "download_link",
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<a href="https://www.google.com"></a>';
        }
    } ]
} );
```

I am wondering if this is possible to add it in the JSON file directly and just link to external sites without the javascript. When I open the inspect it basically just shows a canvas with no way to access what's inside the canvas it seems like.
 I am definitely new to JSON so any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can do this use `fnDrawCallback`

```
        fnDrawCallback: function( oSettings,data,index ){
                $('.linkClassName').on('click', function(event){
                // do whatever u want
               });
           }
```

And add class Name to your link

```
$('#605755').dataTable( {
"columnDefs": [ {
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        return '<a class="linkClassName" href="https://www.google.com">data</a>';
    }
} ]
} );
```

Comment: The fnDrawCallBack would go in the data.json file? I get errors showing up all over when I add the function code. I'm a little confused.